# sql: case when (with in param value)

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

could you please help?

```
SELECT 
(some columns), 
SortOrder = CASE WHEN City = @inParamCity THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
FROM 
dbo.addressBook 
ORDER BY 
SortOrder
```

I tried this and got:

```
Incorrect syntax near '=' ' –
```

Comment: Which **VERSION** (and edition) of SQL Server are you on??? This works flawlessly on my SQL Server 2008 R2 versions.....

Comment: 2008 R2. what you say is weired as some fellows said they see the syntax error (see @Adam Wenger)

Comment: @EladBenda I was incorrect, this works fine on code I just tested as well (SQL Server 2008R2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
(some columns)
FROM 
 dbo.addressBook 
ORDER BY 
 CASE 
   WHEN City = @inParamCity THEN 0 
   ELSE 1 
 END
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be like this?

```
SELECT (some columns), 
CASE City WHEN @inParamCity THEN 0 ELSE 1 END As SortOrder 
FROM dbo.addressBook 
ORDER BY SortOrder
```

Comment: Works, too - but it's really identical to the original posting. No functional difference